# Check duplicate values before inserting data into SQLite in android using eclipse?

Tags: android

Hi can anyone help me in below code?

Once a record with 123 **id** is inserted and next time it should not accept for 123 id again to insert in database.... so please help me to complete this project...

```
package com.example.finder;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.graphics.Color;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TableLayout;

import android.widget.TableRow;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdminActivity extends Activity {

String id,name,email;
SQLiteDatabase db;
TableRow tableRow;
TextView textview,textview1,textview2,textview3,textview4,textview5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("EMP",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMP(id integer primary key,name varchar,email varchar);");
}

public void Submit(View view)
{       
    EditText edittext1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
    EditText edittext2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText edittext3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    id=edittext1.getText().toString();
    name=edittext2.getText().toString();
    email=edittext3.getText().toString();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO EMP(id,name,email) values ('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+email+"');");

    if(id.equals("") && name.equals("") && email.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter details and submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else 
        if(id.equals(""))
       {
            Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter id....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    else
        if(name.equals(""))
           {
            Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Name....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        else
             if(email.equals(""))
            {
            Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
             else 
                { 
                    Toast toast=new Toast (getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    edittext1.setText("");
                    edittext2.setText("");
                    edittext3.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data submitted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    db.close();
                 }
            }

public void Showdata(View view)
{       
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EMP;",null);
    int count=c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    TableLayout tableLayout= new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    TableRow tableRow;
    TextView textview,textview1,textview2,textview3,textview4,textview5;
    tableRow=new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    textview=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview.setText("Empid");
    textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textview.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    textview.setPadding(0, 5, 3, 5);
    tableRow.addView(textview);
    textview4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview4.setText("Ename");
    textview4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textview4.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    textview4.setPadding(15, 10, 3, 5);
    tableRow.addView(textview4);
    textview5=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview5.setText("Email");
    textview5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textview5.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    textview5.setPadding(25, 5, 3, 5);
    tableRow.addView(textview5);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    for (Integer j=0; j< count; j++)
    {
    tableRow= new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    textview1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
    textview2=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
    textview3=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
    textview1.setPadding(0, 5, 3, 5);
    textview2.setPadding(15, 5, 3, 5);
    textview3.setPadding(25, 5, 3, 5);
    tableRow.addView(textview1);
    tableRow.addView(textview2);
    tableRow.addView(textview3);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    c.moveToNext();
    }
    setContentView(tableLayout);
    db.close();
}

public void Exit(View view){
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: You can simply select from database if the id is present or not... And return error on present, else insert the data

Comment: Why don't you make your column unique?

Comment: Select first based upon id. If the cursor count is zero, you know you can insert. You need to move your INSERT as well - you currently appear to do that before validating the input.

Comment: use unique key for column id its work

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by replacing all my inserts and my updates with the so called **upserts** (UPSERT = UPDATE OR INSERT).

```
String[] args = {"1", "newOrOldCategory"}; // where 1 is the category id
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (idColoumn, categoryColumn) VALUES (?, ?)", args);
```

or else (my current implementation):

```
String[] args = {"1", "newOrOldCategory"}; // where 1 is the category id
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("REPLACE INTO table_name (idColoumn, categoryColumn) VALUES (?, ?)", args);
```

Change the table and field names to match yours, and so the values.

Simple and effective: it inserts a record if it doesn't exist, else it updates it with the passed value.

No need to use the **worst practices**:

```
1 - update, check for error and (if so) insert
```

or (WORST EVER!)

```
2 - delete + insert
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can do this by checking the db whether that id exists in the table, with some valid entries. If it is not there, then only insert your new data.

Alternately, if you do not want duplicates altogether, you can also set the id in **auto-increment** mode, and hence there will be no duplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
use unique Key for that column and catch exception while inserting record.

like here name is unique so we cant insert duplicate name.


private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_CLIENT = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME_CLIENTS + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+ NAME +" 
text not null ,"+ MOBILENO +" text not null," +COMPANYNAME+"  text not null,unique ("+NAME+"))";



try
        {
//          

            sqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE_NAME_CLIENT +"("+CLIENTID+","+NAME+","+MOBILENO+","+COMPANYNAME+") 
values " +
                    "('"+clientid+"','"+name+"','"+mobileno+"','"+comname+"')");
        }

        catch(SQLiteConstraintException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter different name....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

may this answer help you
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Phantômaxx found helpful to me. below is with small modification.This will it will not increase your read/write operation.

String[] args = {"1", "newOrOldCategory"}; // where 1 is the category id
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO table_name (idColoumn, categoryColumn) VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT(id) DO NOTHING", args);